# Erdos-Ko-Rado Theorem for $r$ subsets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $F$ be a $n-$element set, where $n$ is finite, and every $r$ subsets intersect. How can I prove that $$|F| \leq {n \choose k} - {n - r + 1 \choose k}$$?

Comment: Seems to me that you got what that theorem says somewhat wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem